# Initializing variable in class

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need to initialize vector in class this way

```
vector<string> test("hello","world");
```

But when I do it, compiler recognize it as an function and give me errors like 
error: expected identifier before string constant etc.

When I do it this way

```
vector<string> test = ("hello","world")
```

it is ok.. Is there some way how to do it in `vector<string> test("xx")` way?

Comment: Are you sure, that `vector<string> test = ("hello","world") ` does what you think it does?

Answer (score 5):

There is no such constructor in std::vector that would allow you to initialize it like that. And your second example evaluates to `"world"` (that's what the `,` operator does) which is what ends up in the vector.

If you want to initialize the vector at declaration time, use an initializer list:

```
vector<string> test = {"hello", "world"};
```

Make sure you build your source code in C++-11 mode for this to work. If you don't have a C++-11 compatible compiler, then you must add the values to the vector afterwards:

```
vector<string> test;
test.push_back("hello");
test.push_back("world");
```

Comment: or just ``string arr[] = {"hello","world"};`` and ``vector<string> test(arr,arr + 2);``

Comment: Actually, the comma operator doesn't do what you think it does either. His second example evaluates to "world".

Comment: string fonoArgs[] = {"1","2","3"}; 
vector<string> fonoS(fonoClass::fonoArgs,fonoClass::fonoArgs+3);           This is giving me errors error: ‘fonoClass::fonoArgs’ is not a type

Comment: @user1751550 I've no idea what `fonoClass` is supposed to be. Anyway, don't use that approach as it introduces a copy of your vector in the form of a plain array. Which is a waste. Just use an initializer list (you didn't mention what compiler you're using.)